# SQLite drop table when row in another table is deleted

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I've been wrestling with setting up a trigger and keep getting the error:

> SQL logic error near "DROP": syntax error

I have several tables main_table, other_one, other_two, etc.

1. **main_table** has several columns with the primary key column named *filehash*
2. The values in the primary key column of **main_table** are also the names of the **other_*** tables

So, if I delete a row in **main_table** with a primary key of **other_one**, I want the trigger to DROP the table **other_one** too

Here's the trigger statement that is producing the error

```
CREATE TRIGGER remove_other_one AFTER DELETE ON 'main_table' 
WHEN (OLD.filehash == 'other_one')
BEGIN
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'other_one' ; 
END remove_other_one;
```

EDIT: the 'fuller' error I get when I run the trigger statement in SQLite DB Browser is:

> near "DROP": syntax error: CREATE TRIGGER remove_other_one AFTER DELETE ON 'main_table' WHEN (OLD.filehash == 'other_one') BEGIN DROP

Comment: Remove the quotes. ```DROP TABLE IF EXISTS other_one```

Comment: Same error when I remove those quotes.

Comment: I think your sqlite version doesn't support ```DROP TABLE IF EXSITS```. Does dropping the table without ```IF EXISTS``` work?

Comment: Same error when I remove the `IF EXISTS` and just use `DROP TABLE`

Comment: Are you executing the query from some script? Can you provide the table_name you are deleting?

Comment: The real table name is `fe87700eda907c8ba76aef38f78ca5598f304b92c5691a7dc5b9d41fd1a752ef` and executing using vb.net (which generates the trigger string)

Comment: Can you add block of code in vb.net where you are forming and executing the query

Comment: I don't think there is any issue with the vb code. As you can deduce from @lad2025 answer, code works in postgress but node SQLite

Answer (score 2):

Based on [SQLite trigger doc](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) I believe that it is not possible:

[image]

There is no option for DDL/dynamic SQL inside trigger.

I guess that you wanted to achieve something like [PostgreSQL DBFiddle Demo 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ac9e3ff64feeb8411d20b7bce6fad140)  and [Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8c639453475d3f27ca51fed2109b38c8)

You could handle your case in application code. Anyway [table per date/customer/hash](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Sales_yymm) almost always indicates poor design and in long run will cause more problems.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this does not work for SQLite (you run it as postgress, but simply select SQLite 3.8 and you'll get the error I now get when I run that code in SQLite Db Browser)

Comment: @Nepaluz Please read my answer again. **As I said what you want to achieve is not possible in SQLite**. I posted PostgreSQL as example how it could be done if SQLite will support DDL or dynamic SQL inside trigger.

Comment: I did 'see' that, but was not hung up on DDL, just getting the right syntax that IS supported. THAT is and was the question (good and/or bad design notwithstanding).

Comment: @Nepaluz: `DROP TABLE` is not supported in a Trigger, so there's no way to get *right syntax*.